# Is it possible for an Android device running API 4.0+ to not support OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es

According to Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html),

> OpenGL ES 2.0 - This API specification is supported by Android 2.2 (API level 8) and higher.

but the [device dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) only shows relative OpenGL support by version.

My concern is that I have many international users with very diverse hardware, but all current users are on Android 4.0 (API level 14) and higher.

If I add OpenGL ES 2.0 as a requirement, would any of my users no longer be supported?

Comment: Make sure you're asking the right question -- there is no such thing as "API 4.0", as the API numbers are integers. "API 4" and "Android 4.0" are both things. OpenGL ES 2.0 was mandatory in Android 4.0, according to the CDD: https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/4.0/android-4.0-cdd.pdf

Comment: It's specified that it should be supported, but there are some devices whose manufacturers claim to support certain specifications, but do not. I'm wondering if any issue with OpenGL ES compatibility is ever seen in the wild, or if this is a non issue.

Comment: The Android CTS tests are used to ensure compliance with the CDD. While they don't exercise the majority of GLES features, CTS will at least ensure that the devices will support GLES 2.x. So you can count on the feature being there, but driver bugs are not unheard-of.

Comment: @fadden Thanks. If you could write this as an answer, I'd like to accept it.

Comment: Done. Also added a link to the 2.3 CDD, in which GLES 2.x was *not* a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Android 4.0 CDD](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/4.0/android-4.0-cdd.pdf), OpenGL ES 2.0 was mandatory in 4.0 (API 14). So adding that as a requirement will not adversely affect any users at that release or later.

Contrast this with the [Android 2.3 CDD](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/2.3/android-2.3.3-cdd.pdf), in which OpenGL ES 2.0 was not mandatory -- section 7.1.5 says only that implementations "SHOULD" support it.

The Android CTS tests work to ensure some level of compliance with the CDD.  They do not thoroughly exercise GLES, but do ensure that the basic features are present.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Anyone from 4.0-7.9 would definitely not be supported.  Most people >=8.0 will be, but open gl also requires hardware support.  Some people on 8 and 9 won't have it.  I expect that by 11, most people would but it isn't guaranteed.